# Raising priority of network interface interrupts on Ubuntu 22 low latency kernel 5.15

Tags: linux-networking, linux-kernel, latency, ubuntu-22.04, irq

I am running Ubuntu 18 on several servers with the low latency kernel.

Previously I have used `chrt` to raise the priority of interrupt threads for the interrupts related to a specific network interface.

Now, on new installations of Ubuntu 22, with the low latency kernel, I no longer see the interrupts for the network cards running as threads and so I cannot increase the priority of those with chrt.

What has changed, and is there a way to increase network card interrupt priority on Ubuntu 22 with lowlatenct kernel?

The reason I am doing this is because I have several instances of an application that syncs small amounts of data with other computers on a 10 ms interval which must not be delayed.

I did find [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuStudio/rtirq) information for UbuntuStudio (although it is a bit old, from 2014) about the *threadirqs* kernel parameter, and I have confirmed that the kernel on my newer servers is built with `CONFIG_IRQ_FORCED_THREADING=y`, but not with `CONFIG_IRQ_FORCED_THREADING_DEFAULT=y` and not `CONFIG_CMDLINE_BOOL=y` and `CONFIG_CMDLINE="threadirqs"`.

**Is it as simple as booting the kernel with the *threadirqs* parameter**, and if so, when and why did the lowlatency kernel change that it does not boot with *threadirqs* by default?

---

**Details**

The servers where my **previous solution works** run Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, with kernel 4.15.0-123-lowlatency

These are the steps I use to raise the priority of the network interface interrupts:

1. I run `grep eno1 /proc/interrupts` to get the list of interrupts for network interface *eno1*

Output:

```
  46:      19627  486510106 1600726600  752055110 1667993661 1758831968 1471240837  895245906  658188895  458440425  918559817 1494584384 1650824561 1492836078 1214143068  920349210  IR-PCI-MSI 5767169-edge      i40e-eno1-TxRx-0
  47:  782983498 3867361290 1350470347 1488832628 1644524179 1306935370 2202471485  885906069  266079923  769050734  767000710 1199122348 1933889985 2475859304  880359145 1207562098  IR-PCI-MSI 5767170-edge      i40e-eno1-TxRx-1
  48:  487247958  557149515 2436993704 1327150410 2327637329 1692350382 1160439225 1234994234  425076063  640500055 1555726813 1469038634 2133556615 1260984085 1076406628 1141316582  IR-PCI-MSI 5767171-edge      i40e-eno1-TxRx-2
  49: 1143028283  802247216  842065588 1507113921 1450442442 1285188073 1414989498 1386700444  961900607  949612962 1176201048  996374473 1392801596 1501055021 1244839988 1568153886  IR-PCI-MSI 5767172-edge      i40e-eno1-TxRx-3
  50:  668676162  585775185  627035622  560691459  545566733  534335154  675644369  619390835  602253370  611090233  610683285  552978104  558929823  827257425  555723069  751315724  IR-PCI-MSI 5767173-edge      i40e-eno1-TxRx-4
  51:  293791983  293018539  290310300  284911609  302624294  171231086  295128963  277943781  299153596  305718023  306559090  265176440  265877422  330072276  275946899  322208126  IR-PCI-MSI 5767174-edge      i40e-eno1-TxRx-5
  52:  191406211  164689451  184092472  163124351  197416416  147238980  150711931  166047824  174857188  176597379  163302040  163989899  169136092  206831749  154774311  195388230  IR-PCI-MSI 5767175-edge      i40e-eno1-TxRx-6
  53:  154062755  152443945  151052334  133925954  161462702  130698860  164068832   88730046  146570114  152839498  140082079  134023798  139525722  178502808  136857972  164157076  IR-PCI-MSI 5767176-edge      i40e-eno1-TxRx-7
  54:  689819152  457848749 1706899545 1350792167 1009016882  750940295 1280794513 1964042727 4293839311  604650430 1394985726 1390827662 1403478542 1032557167 1258596213 1421573353  IR-PCI-MSI 5767177-edge      i40e-eno1-TxRx-8
  55:  561179546 1569329752 1142403865 1952025068 1831162021 1786111309 1819812537 1726432246  809350013 3510981566 1252176327 1188689474 2184195381 1689746731 1808756473 1998075218  IR-PCI-MSI 5767178-edge      i40e-eno1-TxRx-9
  60:  922953009  535440685 1433001681 1370014373 1542680223 1564958146 1905615201 2245129577  606607580  751437652  653813572 1648944839 1339662143 2748851364 1328493925 2197584768  IR-PCI-MSI 5767179-edge      i40e-eno1-TxRx-10
  61:  915173255  898646194  818454435  975220367 1436058787 1258590833 1222669978 1475644158  955884853 1048337605 1028501060 1229229809 1375764724 1619404100 1174614194 1626915747  IR-PCI-MSI 5767180-edge      i40e-eno1-TxRx-11
  62:  663129689  560699700  659990638  564915959  716701151  537167244  709668792  653540652  643175469  609563694  657141242  551578294  496276894  826134713  584425798  782807812  IR-PCI-MSI 5767181-edge      i40e-eno1-TxRx-12
  63:  301178832  272290237  297349011  271058986  300930906  219283819  308344403  269722445  297793600  300198211  271567742  257075242  257586638  275439840  258617424  331559250  IR-PCI-MSI 5767182-edge      i40e-eno1-TxRx-13
  64:  161271542  160600034  162911736  135003940  159159336  126317895  145054883  142236108  153342852  158784173  149385736  130987700  145150304  179008100  100121849  168255307  IR-PCI-MSI 5767183-edge      i40e-eno1-TxRx-14
  65:  174086138  162484310  163432318  142315712  164872478  136966716  168251078  137840006  150045153  156520410  143270315  134481889  152034193  184135755  140295604  167224365  IR-PCI-MSI 5767184-edge      i40e-eno1-TxRx-15
```

2. I run `ps -el | grep irq` to find the pid for each irq thread for *eno1*

Output: (I only show the relevant lines matching irqs 46-65, there are a lot more)

```
1 R     0  1255     2  1   9   - -     0 -      ?        6-01:09:56 irq/46-i40e-eno
1 S     0  1256     2  1   9   - -     0 -      ?        5-13:32:39 irq/47-i40e-eno
1 S     0  1257     2  0   9   - -     0 -      ?        5-04:09:18 irq/48-i40e-eno
1 S     0  1259     2  0   9   - -     0 -      ?        3-12:50:35 irq/49-i40e-eno
1 S     0  1261     2  0   9   - -     0 -      ?        1-19:03:44 irq/50-i40e-eno
1 S     0  1262     2  0   9   - -     0 -      ?        19:55:05 irq/51-i40e-eno
1 S     0  1263     2  0   9   - -     0 -      ?        11:48:06 irq/52-i40e-eno
1 S     0  1264     2  0   9   - -     0 -      ?        09:59:36 irq/53-i40e-eno
1 S     0  1265     2  0   9   - -     0 -      ?        5-09:23:00 irq/54-i40e-eno
1 S     0  1266     2  0   9   - -     0 -      ?        4-19:20:49 irq/55-i40e-eno
1 S     0  1267     2  0   9   - -     0 -      ?        4-19:24:25 irq/60-i40e-eno
1 S     0  1268     2  0   9   - -     0 -      ?        3-10:21:49 irq/61-i40e-eno
1 S     0  1269     2  0   9   - -     0 -      ?        1-20:29:13 irq/62-i40e-eno
1 S     0  1270     2  0   9   - -     0 -      ?        19:24:51 irq/63-i40e-eno
1 S     0  1271     2  0   9   - -     0 -      ?        10:11:11 irq/64-i40e-eno
1 S     0  1273     2  0   9   - -     0 -      ?        10:31:14 irq/65-i40e-eno
```

3. For each of the irq threads for this network interface, I run `chrt -p 80 <thread-pid>`, e.g. `chrt -p 80 1255` for irq/46.

I actually use a combination of grep, awk and xargs to perform these three steps in one:

```
grep $NIC /proc/interrupts \
    | awk '{print substr($1, 0, length($1) - 1);}' \
    | xargs -I% sh -c "ps -e | grep irq/%-" \
    | awk '{print $1;}' \
    | xargs -I% sh -c "echo irq PID %; chrt -p 80 %"
```

```
me@myserver:~$ grep CONFIG_IRQ_FORCED_THREADING /boot/config-4.15.0-123-lowlatency
CONFIG_IRQ_FORCED_THREADING=y
CONFIG_IRQ_FORCED_THREADING_DEFAULT=y

me@myserver:~$ grep CONFIG_CMDLINE /boot/config-4.15.0-123-lowlatency
CONFIG_CMDLINE_PARTITION=y
# CONFIG_CMDLINE_BOOL is not set
```

The newer servers **where this solution does not work** run Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with kernel 5.15.0-79-lowlatency

The results of the first two steps:

1. `grep eno4 /proc/interrupts`

Output:

```
 240:          1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0 1030184410          0  IR-PCI-MSI 5249025-edge      i40e-eno4-TxRx-0
 241:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0 1342657199          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 5249026-edge      i40e-eno4-TxRx-1
 242:          0          0          1 1007985709          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 5249027-edge      i40e-eno4-TxRx-2
 243:          0  995307412          0         21          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 5249028-edge      i40e-eno4-TxRx-3
 244:          0          0          0          0         16          0 1231037185          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 5249029-edge      i40e-eno4-TxRx-4
 245:          0          0          0          0  782521466          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 5249030-edge      i40e-eno4-TxRx-5
 246: 1035173010          0          0          0          0          0          2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 5249031-edge      i40e-eno4-TxRx-6
 247:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  930082293          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 5249032-edge      i40e-eno4-TxRx-7
 248:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  762559502          1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 5249033-edge      i40e-eno4-TxRx-8
 249:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  793943748          0  IR-PCI-MSI 5249034-edge      i40e-eno4-TxRx-9
 250:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0         12          0  998551326          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 5249035-edge      i40e-eno4-TxRx-10
 251:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  975747642          1          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 5249036-edge      i40e-eno4-TxRx-11
 252:          0 1342889081          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0        216          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 5249037-edge      i40e-eno4-TxRx-12
 253:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0         14          0  818489097  IR-PCI-MSI 5249038-edge      i40e-eno4-TxRx-13
 254:          0          0          0          0 1177974058          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 5249039-edge      i40e-eno4-TxRx-14
 255:          0          0  942945250          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0         27  IR-PCI-MSI 5249040-edge      i40e-eno4-TxRx-15
```

2. `ps -el | grep irq`

Output:

```
1 S     0      14       2  0  70 -10 -     0 -      ?        00:06:33 ksoftirqd/0
1 S     0      23       2  0  70 -10 -     0 -      ?        00:14:18 ksoftirqd/1
1 S     0      29       2  0  70 -10 -     0 -      ?        00:30:44 ksoftirqd/2
1 S     0      35       2  0  70 -10 -     0 -      ?        00:03:54 ksoftirqd/3
1 S     0      41       2  0  70 -10 -     0 -      ?        00:09:49 ksoftirqd/4
1 S     0      47       2  0  70 -10 -     0 -      ?        00:02:08 ksoftirqd/5
1 S     0      53       2  0  70 -10 -     0 -      ?        00:06:32 ksoftirqd/6
1 S     0      59       2  0  70 -10 -     0 -      ?        00:05:31 ksoftirqd/7
1 S     0      65       2  0  70 -10 -     0 -      ?        00:03:34 ksoftirqd/8
1 S     0      71       2  0  70 -10 -     0 -      ?        00:00:29 ksoftirqd/9
1 S     0      77       2  0  70 -10 -     0 -      ?        00:04:11 ksoftirqd/10
1 S     0      83       2  0  70 -10 -     0 -      ?        00:02:47 ksoftirqd/11
1 S     0      89       2  0  70 -10 -     0 -      ?        00:13:01 ksoftirqd/12
1 S     0      95       2  0  70 -10 -     0 -      ?        00:01:02 ksoftirqd/13
1 S     0     101       2  0  70 -10 -     0 -      ?        00:06:02 ksoftirqd/14
1 S     0     107       2  0  70 -10 -     0 -      ?        00:06:08 ksoftirqd/15
1 I     0     197       2  0  60 -20 -     0 -      ?        00:00:00 vfio-irqfd-clea
4 S     0     924       1  0  80   0 - 20764 -      ?        00:10:46 irqbalance
```

Kernel build parameters:

```
me@myserver:~$ grep CONFIG_IRQ_FORCED_THREADING /boot/config-5.15.0-79-lowlatency
CONFIG_IRQ_FORCED_THREADING=y

me@myserver:~$ grep CONFIG_CMDLINE_ /boot/config-5.15.0-79-lowlatency
# CONFIG_CMDLINE_BOOL is not set
CONFIG_CMDLINE_PARTITION=y
```